# Java-errors and inability to locate the answer

Tags: java, csv, netbeans

I am writing a program that needs to read a csv-file.
And print out the first word on each line ,plus the first following number right after it.
Strangely enough ,my code can work on a friends computer but not my own.

Editing some nomenclature for methods and variabeles to English (so it would be easier for you guys to read) has yielded even more peculiar errors ,which Netbeans cant help me locate.
A short example of how it should look when it works would be :
Binnenstad 17.460
Bloemekenswijk 8.848
Brugse Poort - Rooigem 17.652
...

The main class code :

```
package autobezit;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Autobezit {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Hood brugge = new Hood("brugge", 50000);
        System.out.println(brugge.getInfo());

        Autobezit situation = new Autobezit();
        situation.initialise();
    }

    public void initialise() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Gent_autobezit.csv"));
        sc.useDelimiter(";");
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
            sc.nextLine();
        }
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            String name= sc.next();
            int number= sc.nextInt();
            Hood hood = new Hood(name,number);
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print(hood.getInfo());
        }        
    }
}
```

And the 'Hoodclass-code'

```
package autobezit;

public class Hood {
    private String name;
    private int numberOfInhabitants;

    public Hood(String name, int numberOfInhabitants){
        this.name=name;
        this.numberOfInhabitants=numberOfInhabitants;
    }

    public String getInfo(){
        return name+" "+numberOfInhabitants;
    }
}
```

The csv file which needs to be read :

```
Gent in Cijfers;;;;;;;;;
Wijken;;;;;;;;;
;Totaal aantal inwoners (2010) [aantal];Aantal huishoudens zonder auto (2001) [huishoudens];Aantal huishoudens met 1 auto (2001) [huishoudens];Aantal huishoudens met 2 auto's (2001) [huishoudens];Aantal huishoudens met 3 of meer auto's (2001) [huishoudens];Percentage huishoudens zonder auto (2001) [huishoudens];Percentage huishoudens met 1 auto (2001) [huishoudens];Percentage huishoudens met 2 auto's (2001) [huishoudens];Percentage huishoudens met 3 of meer auto's (2001) [huishoudens]
Binnenstad;17.460;3.347;4.270;730;64;39,8;50,8;8,7;0,8
Bloemekenswijk;8.848;1.337;1.707;245;20;40,4;51,6;7,4;0,6
Brugse Poort - Rooigem;17.652;2.602;3.428;484;34;39,7;52,4;7,4;0,5
Dampoort;12.030;1.376;2.117;389;30;35,2;54,1;9,9;0,8
Drongen;12.946;520;2.571;1.514;170;10,9;53,8;31,7;3,6
Elisabethbegijnhof - Papegaai;7.086;1.217;1.669;342;24;37,4;51,3;10,5;0,7
Gentbrugge;7.407;596;1.681;598;65;20,3;57,2;20,3;2,2
Kanaaldorpen en -zone;2.438;353;782;247;27;25,1;55,5;17,5;1,9
Ledeberg;9.361;1.351;1.908;262;27;38,1;53,8;7,4;0,8
Macharius - Heirnis;6.695;973;1.253;233;16;39,3;50,6;9,4;0,6
Mariakerke;13.297;858;2.993;1.159;120;16,7;58,3;22,6;2,3
Moscou - Vogelhoek;4.993;508;1.198;294;27;25,1;59,1;14,5;1,3
Muide - Meulestede - Afrikalaan;6.010;806;1.095;133;18;39,3;53,4;6,5;0,9
Nieuw Gent - UZ;8.137;1.554;1.658;231;32;44,7;47,7;6,6;0,9
Oostakker;12.983;691;2.494;1.041;114;15,9;57,5;24;2,6
Oud Gentbrugge;8.431;914;1.900;378;38;28,3;58,8;11,7;1,2
Rabot - Blaisantvest;8.254;1.544;1.327;131;9;51,3;44,1;4,4;0,3
Sint Amandsberg;18.108;1.675;3.956;1.144;99;24,4;57,6;16,6;1,4
Sint Denijs Westrem;5.975;344;1.202;675;97;14,8;51,9;29,1;4,2
Sluizeken - Tolhuis - Ham;10.952;1.575;1.727;209;17;44,6;49;5,9;0,5
Stationsbuurt Noord;11.538;1.856;3.173;615;48;32,6;55,7;10,8;0,8
Stationsbuurt Zuid;7.745;875;1.918;494;56;26,2;57,4;14,8;1,7
Watersportbaan - Ekkergem;7.147;1.637;1.791;244;24;44,3;48,5;6,6;0,6
Wondelgem;14.126;989;3.474;966;68;18;63,2;17,6;1,2
Zwijnaarde;7.100;419;1.521;678;91;15,5;56,1;25;3,4
Totaal;246.719;29.917;52.813;13.436;1.335;30,7;54,2;13,8;1,4
;;;;;;;;;
 ;;;;;;;;;
 ;;;;;;;;;
 ;;;;;;;;;
```

EDIT : Adding an importcommand:

```
import java.util.Locale;
```

// and sc.useLocale.... right after the sc.useDelimiter

```
sc.useLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
```

Has solved some issues. 
The biggest source of problems has been located to be the :

```
while(sc.hasNext())
```

Comment: I do not get it... the code you posted works on your friends PC but not on your own? If it does not work on your PC what exactly happens when executing the program, any exceptions?

Comment: After implementing the Locale.GERMAN, I still get this error
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Answer (score 0):

What are the symptoms on your computer? I am looking at the code and the following aspects seem surprising:

- You throw away the first three lines (sc.nextLine()) but you don't seem to be checking if the file has 3 lines to offer. Are you and your friends using the same CSV?
- The CSV file contains bad input but you are not accounting for it.

I think this is a number format issue and not because the file contains floats but perhaps because the file contains European-formatted numbers (i.e. 17.460 is actually 17460) - the reason it probably works on your friends' computers is because they are using the US locale and the number is interpreted as "17" instead of "17460".

Here is the initialise function rewritten to be more robust and locale-specific:

```
public void initialise() throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Gent_autobezit.csv"));
  sc.useDelimiter(";");
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    sc.nextLine();
  }
  while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String name = sc.next();
    name = name.trim();
    if (name.length() == 0)
      continue; // skip blank lines
    String number = sc.next();
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
    nf.setParseIntegerOnly(true);
    Number frm = nf.parse(number);

    Hood hood = new Hood(name, frm.intValue());
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print(hood.getInfo());
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ali,thx for your help:)I throw away the first three lines because my assignment tells me to.My friend has done the same and is using the exact same file. As for the format ,you are correct again. My friend just pointed out that he uses the following code: 
sc.useDelimiter(";"); 
sc.useLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
// he adds import.util.locale to the head of the file as well
This has resolved a number of the issues already.

We were able to narrow down the errors to this piece of code :
while(sc.hasnext())

If I edit this out and change its condition to stop when it reaches "totaal" it works

Comment: A more general purpose method could be to use the steps that I list in the reimplementation above - notice that it reads the town name and trims it: this will ensure that when you reach the blank lines the code will not proceed further. This is more general purpose in that if your input CSV changes to contain blank lines in other places, this code will continue to work.